# Pilot error and unsubscribing.

Tags: support

Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site. If you no longer want to receive mail from Cooking - Stack Exchange, unsubscribe from all Cooking - Stack Exchange emails with a single click.

I mistakenly clicked UNCUBSCRIBE. I cannot see how to correct my error so that I may recieve email updates.

Please advise (please be gentle on the new kid).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't clicked on that link yet, so I don't know 100% that it'll do it, but:

- go back to the main cooking site
- click on your name at the top of the page
- under your info, there's a horizontal list of 'stats' 'activity', etc ... click on 'prefs'

At the bottom, there will be two checkboxes:

- I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked
- I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited

... I'm guessing that the link changed the setting for one of those two.